# How to get the previous url in rewrite engine?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(register)/?$
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1
```

On the second line, I would not like to intercept or redirect the user. If the url matches the given regex pattern, I would like to perform no operation and the url user requested should go where it was intended to. How do I do this?

Comment: _I would like to perform no operation_ You would like to show a 404?

Comment: No. If the url matches the pattern given, it should not take the user elsewhere other than the url the user requested previously. If the user requests /register/ then it should take the user to /register/

Comment: So what does `register` have? A `register.php` to execute and show?

Comment: register takes the user to register/index.php

Comment: What all else do you have in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: after the code snippet that I posted, I have this line `
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1`

Comment: So, you are by default redirecting all requests to profile.php?

Comment: Yes, but except for /register/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to redirect all requests to `profile.php` except for `register`, you can add an additional rewrite condition to only redirect if request URI is not `register`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/register/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1
```

**Demo:** https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=5f7d67b4-a374-5195-975e-a9742a685fdf

Comment: Can you please explain the second line?

Comment: @KMABadshah It checks if `request_uri` is NOT `/register`. If yes, then rewrite rule is executed, else the request works as is.

Comment: @KMABadshah The NOT for the regex pattern is accomplished with a `!` at the beginning.

Comment: @KMABadshah But make sure no one has a `username` as `register`.

Comment: What does the [NC] mean?

Comment: @KMABadshah `[NC]` is to perform a _case-insensitive_ match.

Comment: One last thing. Can you provide a good  source to learn these things other than the apache docs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218969/discussion-between-kma-badshah-and-vivek-23).

Comment: @KMABadshah To be honest, the official docs is only good source I found. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html You can use this testing tool to check your .htaccess accuracy.  https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/